# Getting modal dialog to respond to Enter

Tags: jquery

I have a modal dialog box, below, that reads an input field when the Save button is clicked. This works fine.  But I'd also like to trigger the Save button function when Enter is entered in the input field. Is there a simple way to do that?

Thanks

```
 dialog1$ = $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
             .html("<div><h6>Save as . . .</h6><input id='user-input' type='text'></div>");
    $('#user-input').val(g.last_save_name);
    dialog1$.dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Save Websheet', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Save: function () {
                savePage($("#user-input").val());
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply bind the keypress event to the div/element that contains your dialog. This should work.

```
$(dialog1$).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
          savePage($("#user-input").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear where to put this code. In addition to doing the savePage() I want to also close the dialog but _this_ is only valid in the dialog() call.